# Fragment: onCreateView se ejecuta 3 veces

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para Android. La base es el **template** de Android Studio (bottom navigation). Para realizar esa navegación estoy usando **fragments**.

Al cambiar de opción mediante el *bottom navigation* resulta que dicho *fragment* parece que se ejecuta tres veces. Parece esto porque en el *Adapter* añado una imagen de forma dinámica, en lugar de añadirse una vez, se añade tres veces:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código del fragment es el siguiente:

```
public class girls_fragment extends Fragment {

private WodDbAdapter mWodAdapter;
ListView lvWods;
private  View rootview;



public girls_fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    lvWods = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lvwGirlsList);
    mWodAdapter = new WodDbAdapter(getContext());
    mWodAdapter.open();
    fillData();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_girls_fragment,container,false);




    return rootview;
}

private void fillData(){
    Cursor mGirlsCursor = mWodAdapter.fetchAllWods("girl");
    getActivity().startManagingCursor(mGirlsCursor);
    String [] from = new String[]{WodDbAdapter.KEY_NOMBRE,};
    int [] to = new int []{R.id.txtvwGirlName};

    girlsListFragmentCursoAdapter mGirlsAdapter = new girlsListFragmentCursoAdapter(rootview.getContext(),mGirlsCursor);

    lvWods.setAdapter(mGirlsAdapter);
}

}
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad esto es un comportamiento "normal", tu Fragment seguramente se esta cargando en un "paginador", por esta razón simpre se carga el Fragmento visible y además se pre-cargan los fragmentos izquierdo y derecho.

Si deseas limitar el número de Fragments que se cargan en el "paginador", puedes usar el método

> [setOffscreenPageLimit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) Establece el número de páginas que deben
>   conservarse en cualquier lado de la página actual en la jerarquía de
>   vistas en estado inactivo.

Por ejemplo, si deseas limitar a solo un elemento en el pager, lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

*El minimo permitido es 1